# A simple C exercise going wrong: Trying to return a pointer to an array of two strings

Tags: c

"Return a pointer to an array of two strings. The first is the characters
   of string s that are at even indices and the second is the characters from
   s that are at odd indices"

```
char **parity_strings(const char *s) {

char** parity = malloc(sizeof(char*) * 2);
char even_strings[] = "";
char odd_strings[] = "";
int x = 0;
int y = 0;

for (int i = 0; i < strlen(s); i++) {

    if ((i % 2) == 0) {

      even_strings[x] = s[i];
      x++;
    }
    else {
       odd_strings[y] = s[i];
       y++;
    }
}

parity[0] = even_strings;
parity[1] = odd_strings;



return parity;

}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    char **r = parity_strings(argv[1]);
    printf("%s %s %s", r[0], r[1], argv[1]);
    return 0;
}
```

My logic makes sense but the output is always incorrect. For example, with input `ababab` I get back `ababab` while the expected output is `aaa bbb ababab`. What did I do wrong?

Comment: `char even_strings[] = "";` has length 1 - the terminator. So the indexing `even_strings[x] = s[i];` is UB, and so is returning pointers to local strings that have gone out of life.

Comment: You might consider reviewing how C handles strings again.  They are not high level objects, but instead are just arrays of `char`, filled with ASCII codes, and a `nul` zero at the end.   Not something you can use as an rvalue.   (pointers to strings though, you could)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The string named `even_strings` is a local variable, so its memory will be freed after your function returns, so it is not valid to try to return a pointer to it to the caller.

Try changing this line:

```
char even_strings[] = "";
```

to something like this:

```
char * even_strings = malloc(some_size);
```

The same goes for your `odd_strings` string.

Also, be sure to  pick a good value for `some_size` so that your program allocates enough memory for each string so that it can hold all the data you are writing to it.

Comment: Thank you! That's very helpful.

Answer (score 2):

`even_strings` and `odd_strings` are arrays of size 1 each. Your code writes out of bounds (`even_strings[x] = s[i]`, `odd_strings[y] = s[i]`). Furthermore, they're local variables that cease to exist once `parity_strings` returns, so the returned pointers are garbage.